# How to sum values in a loop

Tags: loops, vbscript

How do I sum values in this existing vbs loop?
I want to create a function that sums (adds up) the values len(sLine)
and outputs a line oOutStream.WriteLine mySum

I don't know 1) how to code the function and 2) whether to nest it in the existing loop or create a new loop.

```
Function MyOp()
Dim nLine, sLine, nCount

nCount = 1
Do Until oInStream.AtEndOfStream
nLine = oInStream.Line
sLine = oInStream.ReadLine

nCount = nCount +1
oOutStream.WriteLine "<p id='" & Pad(nLine, 2, 0) & "'>" & sLine & "</p>"

Loop
MyOp = nCount

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right then...

```
Function MyOp()
    Dim nLine, sLine, nCount, nLen

    nCount = 1
    Do Until oInStream.AtEndOfStream
        nLine = oInStream.Line
        sLine = oInStream.ReadLine
        nLen  = nLen + Len(sLine)

        nCount = nCount +1
        oOutStream.WriteLine "<p id='" & Pad(nLine, 2, 0) & "'>" & sLine & "</p>"
    Loop
    oOutStream.WriteLine nLen
    MyOp = nCount
End Function
```

But you can get the same result with `File.Size` property without need of counting.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fLen    = fso.GetFile("file.ext").Size
```

**P.S.** A self correction: `ReadLine` remove trailing newline character(s) (Chr(13) & Chr(10)), therefore the sum you get with `Len(string)` will be less than `Size` property.

As for the function, I test it with text file, and have no idea how you get `TextStream` object form EditPlus without saved file. How you do that, if not a secret?

Comment: Thanks Seeker, I tried both methods but couldn't get them to work. As far as the fso method, I don't have a saved file but an open text document. My script runs as a filter in a text editor (EditPlus). I tried changing the fso variable to a string value.

I also tried working with the loop, but couldn't get that to work either. I will try again a little later.

Comment: To create a text filter in EditPlus, you have to use the User tool (Preferences/User tools) feature to add a custom script. There are  sample working text filters (vbs and javascript) for EditPlus on the web.  I can help you configure one if you need help.

Comment: @ggg I do not use EditPlus, I was just curious. As for the function, 
I made a very small modification to yours and if your initial function works then my should work too. And I'm not sure if I can help with something more.